# How closely is deconstruction tied to the plurality of meaning?

Tags: meaning, deconstruction

How closely is deconstruction tied to the plurality of meaning?

> the [instability](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/299510594_Deconstructing_the_library_with_Jacques_Derrida_creating_space_for_the_Other_in_bibliographic_description_and_classification) and plurality of meaning

[Derrida](http://pmc.iath.virginia.edu/issue.904/15.1plotnitsky.html) on Heidegger:

> the break with the horizon of communication as the communication of
>   consciousnesses and presences, and as the linguistic or semantic
>   transport of meaning; (2) the subtraction of all writing from the
>   semantic horizon or the hermeneutic horizon which, at least as a
>   horizon of meaning, lets itself be punctured by writing; (3) the
>   necessity of, in a way, separating the concept of polysemia [as a
>   controlled or controllable plurality of meaning] from the concept I
>   have elsewhere named dissemination [an uncontrollable plurality of
>   meaning]

**Is it sufficient to offer a different reading of something, which also allows the received interpretation, in order for it to be deconstructive?** As I think Derrida says can be done with Aristotle [emphasis mine]

> "Without a doubt, Aristotle thinks of time on the basis of ousia as
>   parousia, on the basis of the now, the point, etc. And yet an entire
>   **reading could be organized that would repeat in Aristotle's text both
>   this limitation and its opposite**."

What other theories of text, which do not fall under 'deconstruction', incorporate a plurality of meanings?

Comment: any help with the downvote?

Comment: I know it’s difficult with this material, but the more “innocently” and naively you can approach it, the more likely others are to be able to follow... (Specifically maybe you could be a little more open and direct about what what exactly you’re looking for in a great answer to the question...)